# Run a read-only test in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to compare the read performance of different storage systems using Spark ,e.g. HDFS/S3N. I have written a small Scala program for this:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel

object SimpleApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("WordCount")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val file = sc.textFile("s3n://test/wordtest")
    val splits = file.map(word => word)
    splits.saveAsTextFile("s3n://test/myoutput")
  }
}
```

My question is, is it possible to run a read-only test with Spark? For the program above, isn't saveAsTextFile() causing some write as well?

Comment: You might want to try something lighter than `saveAsTextFile`, something like `count`, for example.

Comment: @MikelUrkia could you add that as an answer that can be accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if that is possible at all. In order to run a *transformation*, a posterior *action* is necessary.

From the official [*Spark* documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/programming-guide.html#rdd-operations):

> All transformations in Spark are lazy, in that they do not compute their results right away. Instead, they just remember the transformations applied to some base dataset (e.g. a file). The transformations are only computed when an action requires a result to be returned to the driver program.

Taking this into account, `saveAsTextFile` might not be considered the lightest from the wide range of actions available. Several lightweight alternatives exists, actions like `count` or `first`, for example. These would leverage almost the totality of the work to the transformations phase, making you able to measure the performance of your solution.

You might want to check the [available actions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/programming-guide.html#actions) and choose the one that best fits your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Yes."saveAsTextFile" writes the RDD data to text file using given path.